# Detached Entity Passed to Pesist when Using EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

I Have two entity's mapped with one to many relationship.I am persist two objects In Database with Id 1,2

with same type

scenario 1. I am Trying to remove Id '1' with `getEntityManager.remove(object1)` its show the

detached entity passed to persist for Child entity..even DB record found.

scenario 2. when I am Trying to remove Id '2' with `getEntityManager.remove(object2)` its deleting the record 2 .

this Exception occur only for before enter record with same time.

after I am close and re open the page I am remove the ID 1,2 from Db its successfully worked.

Comment: Please fix your formatting, show us the code, and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Thanx for responding Mr JB Nizet .i can upload the code please tell me the sol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> com.manam.mobee.persist.entity.MobeeLabelTemplate#null

Inspect the `mobeeLabel.getMobeeLabelTemplates()` inside the `deleteLabel()` and make sure they have the **id**.

---

***Edit:***

You need the id in the objects to update and delete. Before deleting mobeeLabel, perform a findById and then remove it. There should be some non-inserted mobeeLabelTemplates (or not updated - ids out of sync with the db). Try something like this:

```
MobeeLabel freshMobeeToDelete = (MobeeLabel) getEntityManager().find(MobeeLabel.class, mobeeLabel.getId());
getEntityManager().remove(freshMobeeToDelete);
```

Comment: IN deleteLabel()  I am getting the mobeeLabel.getMobeeLabelTemplates() objects .but It throws exception detached suppose first time I added database to three objects In that same time I am removeing one or two objects its show detached ,suppose I am remove the thrid objects its deteted.

Comment: Thanx for responding. i will check it this one now but still same exception is getting .last record is deleting but previoes saved record are not deleted ,but when i reload the page its working good